# How to hide angular2 module implementation for particular user role in Angular2 + ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-modules

In the application i should ensure that particular user role, can't see some component implementation, that was designed for other user roles (admin must see everything, and user shouldn't see admin specific stuff).

What would be the best practice for it?

Current solution:

In my `asp.net mvc` application i have `systemjs.config.js` file that points to `Main` angular module that bootstraps entire `angular2` application.

```
packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
```

I do have modules:

```
AdminModule
UserModule
SharedModule
AdminSpecificComponentsModule
```

I don't want `User` to see implementation of `AdminSpecificComponentsModule`. Html templates, js...

So i use 2 `systemjs.config.js` files. Instead of single `Main` module entry point having 2 `MainAdmin` and `MainUser`, where `MainUser` not injecting `AdminSpecificComponentsModule`.

Each user role has int's own `MVC View/Controller` (calling it workplace), where appropriate `systemjs.config.js` being referenced.

```
<script src="../user-systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<user-app></user-app>
```

And

```
<script src="../admin-systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<admin-app></admin-app>
```

In production environment we'll have to boundle JS, HTML for each user role separately and ensure `User` can't serve bundles that intended for `Admin` role.

Is there more clever way of doing such a things using that technology stack?

Thanks in advance